# Using Regex as delimeter to split a string

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I want to split the following strings into two substrings.
"somestring(otherstring)"

I came with the following regex split

```
"somestring(otherstring)".split(/(.+)\((.+)\)/)
```

but this excludes the following strings, which dont have the substring in braces..
"somestring"

how can change the regex so that, even if there is not substring of the pattern "(otherstring)", it still generates the first substring as output.

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>> "somestring(otherstring)".split(/[()]/)
=> ["somestring", "otherstring"]
>> "somestring".split(/[()]/)
=> ["somestring"]
```

Comment: works perfectly and seems beautiful too. it would be of great help, if you can you run me through what the regex is doing. thanks.

Comment: both `(` and `)` are inside the square brackets. this is called a character class. it means split on either `(` or `)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this as the regex: `/([^\(\)]+)(?:\((.+)\))?/`.